# Bending a Laser Beam

Tags: visible-light, relativity, laser, refraction

We can bend a Laser beam by varying the refraction coefficient of the air.

We can bend a Laser beam by dispersing into the air small particles that have the same effect on the Laser Beam and small water particles have a on light when they make a rainbow.

We can bend a Laser beam if we have sufficient mass available to attract the Laser beam.

If you were to make an umbrella for rain using a Laser beam what technical approach would you use, please?

(If you were to bend a Laser Beam what technical approach would you use, please?)

Say that I want to bend the light trajectory. I can do it varying the refraction index of the air, I can do it using a dispersion of transparent particles into the air (making a rainbow effect), I can do this by having a very heavy mass under the light beam. If you were asked to do this (to bend a light beam), how would you do this, please?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about bending a light beam.

You are suggesting three ways:

1. varying the refraction index of air. By doing this, at the edge of the different parts of air (like different media), where the refraction index differs, light's path would change
2. dispersion of transparent particles into the air, like a rainbow effect. By doing this, you would actually separate the different wavelength photons inside white light from the Sun (the light of the Sun is white, not yellow).
3. heavy mass under the light beam. This is the only solution that would actually use stress-energy (not mass) to bend the trajectory of photons.

If you are really talking about the bending of trajectory of photons, the only way to do it without interacting with them via real particles (that is no diffraction) is using a object with stress-energy. The objects gravitational zone would bend the trajectory of the photons, but the effect is so little with available energies, that you would possibly need a small black hole to bend the trajectories in a useful way.

I do not have information on how this could help against rain, as a laser beam, though it might have high frequency (energy), I am not aware of any method that could stop a falling raindrop. The only way I can think of is if the laserbeam has enough energy, it could vaporize the drops and as steam they could stay in the air above the laserbeam (umbrella) if you used some kind of ventilation.

Comment: Yes a Laser beam could vaporize a rain drop. Thank you for the answer. :)